# sql where clause issue with date older than 5 years

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I not include people with a birth date older than 5 years from today's date? Here is what I have, I just dont know how to put it in my where clause.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, age, gender, birthdate
FROM Person
WHERE ... ... ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
dateadd(year,-5, getdate()) >= birthdate
```

Comment: +1 I think this condition will be faster than use `DATEDIFF`. In this case MSSQL can use index on birthdate.

Comment: @Andrew Bickerton -- thanks. I really appreciate it. To everyone else who contributed their suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
datediff(year,yourdate,getdate()) > 5
```

Comment: @frian . . . `SUBTIME()` is not a SQL Server function.  The question is labelled "tsql".

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is:

```
where birthdate <= dateadd(year, -5, getdate())
```

The reason this is "best" is because all the operations are on non-columns values (`getdate()` rather than `birthdate`).  This allows the engine to take advantage of an index on `birthdate` when processing this `where` clause.

Comment: imho this does not allow index usage (does it?), because `getdate()` isn't constant.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste . . . You wouldn't have an index on `getdate()`.  You would have an index on `birthdate`.

Comment: Yea obviously! Thanks. Good we cleared up, somehow I got confused by your wording, sorry :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEADD` to subtract 5 years from todays date:

```
 SELECT firstname, lastname, age, gender, birthdate
   FROM Person
  WHERE birthdate < DATEADD(year, -5, GETDATE())
```